# Rounding hours in data frame using Python -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data frame that I have created in python that contains data about plants that were measured one time every one hour. The problem is that the original intention was to measure them at the same hour every day- 10:00, 11:00,12:00...
but in real life the plants were measured with a littlle different in time so now I have too many rows.

[image]

as you can see here, plant D10A was measured one day at 10:02, one day at 10:09, 10:14 ,10:17 ......
I want all of those to be under "10:00" and then to have less rows.

**My end goal is to have the same table but with rounded hours  instead of the exact time**

Comment: please provide little text snippets of your example, and not images as the links may expire/be broken/ or redirecting to another source. Besides, it can speed up things, as users can copy and paste the sample data, to create their own.

Comment: the code I have is just the one that created this display so I don't know if it's relevant to the question

Comment: I just ask you to provide of your sample data as a text, so I can copy and paste directly without having to deal with re-creating it as it is time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# here is the piece of your dataframe:

            6/17/2019   6/18/2019
plant   Hour        
D10A    10:02   NaN     NaN
        10:09   NaN     0.33
        10:14   NaN     NaN
        10:17   0.777   NaN
        10:19   NaN     NaN

col = df.columns
df = df.reset_index()
df['hr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df.fillna(0).groupby(['plant','hr'])[col].max()

Out[1]:
            6/17/2019   6/18/2019
plant   hr          
D10A    10  0.777       0.33
```

### Upd: for just rounding Hours, here is the code:

```
col = df.columns
df = df.reset_index()
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).apply(lambda x: str(x.hour) + ':00')
df.set_index(['plant', 'Hour'])[col]

Out[2]:

            6/17/2019   6/18/2019
plant   Hour        
D10A    10:00   NaN     NaN
        10:00   NaN     0.33
        10:00   NaN     NaN
        10:00   0.777   NaN
        10:00   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: it looks good but I get error message: KeyError: "Index([u'6/17/2019', u'6/18/2019', u'6/19/2019', u'6/20/2019', u'6/21/2019',\n       u'6/22/2019', u'6/23/2019', u'6/24/2019', u'6/25/2019'],\n      dtype='object', name=u'date') not in index"  , and just to ensure- I should first round the hours and then to change the apply it to the data frame?

Comment: now it worked, thank you. If ou can explain a little about this line df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).apply(lambda x: str(x.hour) + ':00') , especially the x.hour and how it knows to add the 00 it will be great.

Comment: sure! 1) df['Hour'] - we get the 'hour' column values as it is. so it's series of string '10:02', '10:09'...  2) pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']) - now it converts to series of datetime types. So it has additional methods and attributes. Every item now has attribute .hour which returns exactly the hours value (10 in our case). 3) Then we applying the lambda function to every item. Lambda function get the hour-part (10 in our cases), convert it to string ('10') and concatenate it with another string ':00'. so it gives string ('10:00') and return it back. All of this gives you series of such string